# Probability that package installed using pip install --user will be loadable

Tags: python, pip

My software needs to install packages on arbitrary container images that have python 3.5+. The module must then be loadable by running `python3 -c 'import my_module'`.

I plan to use `python3 -m pip install my-package --user` command to install the packages. The `--user` work around the containers where the active user is not root.

Unfortunately I've vaguely heard about cases where the user directory where pip installs packages is not in PATH on some systems or something like that.

Would that affect the ability to import the installed package?

What command-line should I use to install packages reliably?

Answer (score 0):

as long as it's in your path such as .local/bin or in .local or python PATH's you can run it as if it was in /usr PATH

Comment: >"as long as it's in your path such as .local/bin or in .local or python PATH's" - Does python automatically searches '.local' even if it's not in OS PATH?